# Calling external REST API using ABP.IO

Tags: abp

I want to call External REST API in my Domain Service, what is the best way to do that in abp framework, and where I can put this API Url and how to get it in my Domain Service?

- ABP Framework version: v5.3
- Project Type: MVC

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a http client, like RestSharp (https://restsharp.dev/) to be able to call an external api.
Since the api url might change, you can add it in the appsettings.json file and inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration into your domain service constructor.